# Wrong object is being detected on OnMouseUpAsButton

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, mouse

In my 2d game project I have an object A moving above map. Both object and map have colliders (circle collider and polygon collider respectively), as well as actions to be performed on OnMouseUpAsButton. Objects are displayer properly in the game, however, when I click on the object it usually detects map (usually as in sometimes it detects the object if I press in the very centre of the object). How to ensure that my objects of type A are always checked first for MouceUp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found an answer that seems to work- even though it is a 2d project set Z transform position of the object to -1. It's a hack but it works